# reading a UTF-16 file in Linux

Tags: c++

I have the following program which reads a file into a string buffer.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

constexpr int BUFSIZE = 1024;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream ifs(argv[1], std::ifstream::binary);
    if(!ifs)
        return 1;

    string buffer(BUFSIZE, L'\0');
    ifs.read(&buffer[0], BUFSIZE);

    cerr << ifs.gcount() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It prints out the expected 1024.

The following program which is supposed to read into a wstring buffer doesn't work though.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

constexpr int BUFSIZE = 1024;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::wifstream ifs(argv[1], std::ifstream::binary);
    if(!ifs)
        return 1;

    wstring buffer(BUFSIZE, L'\0');
    ifs.read(&buffer[0], BUFSIZE);

    cerr << ifs.gcount() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ir prints out 0 with the same file.

As you can see the only difference is changing the stream to a wstream and the buffer to a wstring.

I've tried both g++ 8.2.1 and clang++ 6.0.1 under OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

Where is the problem/my error?

Comment: IRC, `wchar` is NOT UTF-16. It's NOT UTF at all. On Unix-like it's 32 bit wide.
You should use `char16_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `std::basic_ifstream<char16_t>` and `std::u16string` for UTF-16. `std::wifstream` and `std::wstring` are not appropriate because the width of `wchar_t` is implementation defined. In Linux in particular, it is (usually?) 32 bits wide.

Same for character literals. You should use `u'\0'` etc. instead of `L'\0'`.